# bash script who make user from a csv file

Tags: bash, csv

Hello everyone I have to do a bash script who make user from csv. So I did it but didn't work when I launch it he make me only once user from csv file and its the wrong name that the csv file:

```
Id,Prenom,Nom,Mdp,Rôle
1001,Octavia,Blake,U9nh4W,User
1002,Bellamy,Blake,2Nn2Ja,Admin
1003,Abigail ,Griffin,v8G2Zc,User
1004,Finn,Collins,N98rqT,User
1005,Jasper,Jordan,8Ltk4R,User
1006,Raven,Reyes,n45RQz,Admin
1007,Monty ,Green,Y3yzP4,User
1008,Clarke,Griffin,f56SxP,Admin
1009,Marcus,Jane,bNw4T9,User
1010,John ,Murphy,zT5fH2,User
1011,Wells,Jaha,z4b5RJ,User
1012,Maddy ,Griffin,9jqW9F,Admin
```

And that is the code I take from stackoverflow and edit it:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

Ajua_input="/home/sofiane/Téléchargements/Shell_Userlist.csv"
declare -a Id
declare -a Prenom
declare -a Nom
declare -a Mdp
declare -a Role

while IFS=, read -r Id Prenom Nom Mdp Role;
do 
        Id+=("$Id")
        Prenom+=("$Prenom")
        Nom+=("$Nom")
        Mdp+=("$Mdp")
        Role+=("$Role")

done<$Ajua_input

for index in "${!username[@]}";
do
        sudo groupadd "${role[$index]}";
        sudo useradd -g "${role[$index]}" \ 
                     -d "/home/${username[index]}" \
                     -s "/bin/bash" \
                     -p "$(echo "${pass[$index]}" | openssh passwd -1 -stdin)" "${username[$index]}"
done
```

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: I don't understand _but didn't work_. What is the meaning of _and its the wrong name that the csv file_?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it thank you

```
#!/bin/bash
export IFS=","

cat /home/sofiane/Téléchargements/Shell_Userlist.csv | while read Id Prenom Nom Mdp Role
    do
    sudo userdel $Prenom-$Nom
    sudo groupdel $Prenom-$Nom
    sudo useradd $Prenom-$Nom
        echo "$Prenom-$Nom:$Mdp" | sudo chpasswd
        sudo usermod -u $Id "$Prenom-$Nom"
                if [ $Role = "Admin" ]
                then
                sudo usermod -aG sudo "$Prenom-$Nom"
                fi
        done
```